# ‘::at_quick_exit’ has not been declared error

Tags: c++, c++11, ubuntu, g++, g++4.9

I have following simple c++ program.

```
 #include <memory>
 std::unique_ptr<int> test;
```

When I compile it I am getting following error.

```
g++ -c structTemp.cpp -std=c++11

In file included 
from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ext/string_conversions.h:41:0,
from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/basic_string.h:2850,
from /usr/include/c++/4.9/string:52,
from /usr/include/c++/4.9/stdexcept:39,
from /usr/include/c++/4.9/array:38,
from /usr/include/c++/4.9/tuple:39,
from /usr/include/c++/4.9/functional:55,
from /usr/include/c++/4.9/memory:79,
from structTemp.cpp:1:
***/usr/include/c++/4.9/cstdlib:126:11: error: ‘::at_quick_exit’ has not been declared
using ::at_quick_exit;
           ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/cstdlib:149:11: error: ‘::quick_exit’ has not been declared
using ::quick_exit;***
           ^
Compilation exited abnormally with code 1 at Thu Nov 12 14:45:03
```

Does anyone know why this compilation error is taking place and how it should be fixed?

Comment: why are you not using g++? it's a cpp program so should be compiled with g++

Comment: `std` is missing before those colons.  An out-of-control find+replace in your editor, maybe?

Comment: @rz3r0 I tried with g++ and gcc both giving the same error.

Comment: @HansPassant /usr/include/c++/4.9/cstdlib is a standard include file. I did not even open it.

Comment: I tried your program and it compiled for me. Is it possible that your installation of gcc is corrupt?  ``` gcc --version
gcc-4.8.real (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.```

Comment: @SashaPachev My version of g++ is:

` g++ (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13) 4.9.2
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.`

Why do you suspect the g++ installation is corrupt?

Comment: Because the exact same code compiles with no errors on my system on a slightly older version of gcc. So either a bug was introduced into 4.9, or your installation has a problem - e.g alternative conflicting gcc version installed, stale files left from the previous install, etc.